# Accessing specific vendor's domains (voice-acl.com, maccesssmspush.com) fails from within Google Compute instances and GKE pods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

My Google Compute Instances as well as my GKE pods are unable to reach the following domains :-

> maccesssmspush.com
>   voice-acl.com

I am able to access (curl) these domains from everywhere else in the world including my local network and AWS instances from all over the world.

I have also checked with the vendor if they have blacklisted some IP's and it isn't the case.

Why would Google be blocking access to these domains, they belong to one of the most widely used SMS vendors in India and are used by many many other companies.

Comment: I can't connect to `voice-acl.com` from my local ISP. `Failed to connect to voice-acl.com port 80: Connection refused`. `curl maccesssmspush.com` just times out. I've learned not to trust vendors' statements in this regard - it's very possible support/sales doesn't know what the sysadmins have in place.

Comment: Hey, for voice-acl.com its 443. So you can try curl and use the https:// prefix . maccesssmspush.com requires whitelisting by the vendor which is working for my AWS instance.

Answer (score 0):

From time to time, some IP addresses are blacklisted in public databases.

Google has no control over blacklist databases and cannot remove IP addresses from them directly.

This may be a temporary issue depending on how long the specific IP is on the blacklist, however you can ask for the IP to be [removed](https://www.dnsbl.info/blacklist-removal.php) from the [blacklist](https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php)